# Cakephp system for update the row for given id if no id exists, create a new row

Tags: php, cakephp

What is do you think is the best way to create a procedure where request is made and if there are any existing id in the database, update if not create a new one.

I was using something like below and it seems to work but is there are better way?

```
$id = $this->User->findByFacebookId($facebook);

                   if($id){
                       $this->User->set(array(
                          'facebook_id' => $facebook,
                           'longitude' => $longitude,
                           'latitude' => $latitude,
                           'firstname' => $firstname,
                           'surname' => $surname
                       ));
                       $this->User->id = $id['User']['id'];
                       $this->User->save($this->data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, CakePHP basically does this by default. If your data has no `id` field an `INSERT` statement is issued, whereas if there is an `id` field it issues `UPDATE ... WHERE ID = ?`.

Just to show how simply this can be done, below is a way to do the same without even calling `Model::set()` or updating the `Model::id` property:

```
    // get existing record (so we can get value of `id` field)
    $existing = $this->User->findByFacebookId($facebook);

    // if record exists, map data to correct record `id`
    if ($existing) {
        $this->data['User']['id'] = $existing['User']['id'];
    }

    // save data to table (`id` determines if INSERT or UPDATE)
    $this->User->save($this->data);
```

Comment: Thanks mate I actually needed to use set because some field values are not to be filled and I just wanted to negate one of the column.